# אנשי כנסת הגדולה and סנהדרין relationship

Tags: sanhedrin, anshei-knesset-hagedolah

What is the relationship between the אנשי כנסת הגדולה and the Sanhedrin?  Is the 70 of the Sanhedrin always included in the 120 of the כנסת הגדולה?  In the time both existed what was the division of responsibilities? Which was considered superior?

Answer (score 5):

From what I've read, there are a lot of disagreements among both rabbis and academics about what the exact role of the Knesset Hagedolah was, particularly in light of the Sanhedrin/Beit Din Hagadol (Great Court) (for example, both the Torah says that there need to be 71 sages (Moshe and seventy elders) and we know that that's how the Sanhedrin was structured, but there were 120 men in the Knesset Hagedolah). There are also disagreements about the exact structure and authority of the Sanhedrin, in light of sources that use similar terms to seemingly describe completely contrasting things (for example, the priestly Sanhedrin described by Josephus, when we know there were also non-priests in the Sanhedrin<sup>1</sup>).<sup>2</sup> It's my understanding that there's no definitive answer at the moment for your question, but I can present some different views on the subject.

[Rabbi Yaakov Medan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaaqov_Medan) in his essay in Hebrew "[Introduction To C. Chefetz's Essay On the Persian and Median Empire](http://www.herzog.ac.il/vtc/tvunot/mega14_medan.pdf)", pg. 76, Megadim 14, brought two views about the Knesset Hagedolah:

1. [Rabbi Shlomo Goren](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Goren) in Torat Ha'Moadim opined that the Knesset Hagedolah was comprised of three courts: The Great Court of 71 men, and two secondary courts, of 23 men each (see for example [Mishna Sanhedrin 1:6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Sanhedrin.1.6?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi)). This brings us to 117 men, and adding to them the prophets Chaggai, Zechariah and Malachi, we get 120 men.
2. While accepting that Rabbi Goren's idea of the structure of the Knesset made most sense, Rabbi Medan himself believed that the number 120 was never thought of as a must for a high spiritual and judicial leadership institution. Rather, Chazal concluded that the Knesset Hagedolah itself *happened* to be made up of 120 men, based on the number of elders that appear in Ezra and Nechemiah, together with Chaggai, Zechariah, Malachi and Shimon Hatzaddik (or variant possibilities, such as Daniel, Mishael, Azaryah and Chanayah).

A third view, brought by [Rabbi Reuven Margolies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuvein_Margolies) in his book "The Basis of the Mishna and its Editing Process" (יסוד המשנה ועריכתה), 4th edition<sup>3</sup>, pg. 38-39 says that when the central court was being established in the time of Ezra and Nechemiah, the sages were unable to decide who would sit on the court and who wouldn't, so they decided to put everyone who was fit for the role (which happened to be 120 men), and waited until 49 passed away, thus returning to the customary number of 71. Only from then on, when an elder died or was unable to continue in his post, he was replaced by another elder. In his view, this is also the meaning of the term "[שיירי כנסת הגדולה](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pirkei_Avot.1.2?lang=bi)" - from the moment that the first of the 120 elders passed away, the Knesset was now the "remainder" of the Knesset. This judicial body continued to exist for a couple of centuries until eventually becoming known as the "Sanhedrin" (the Aramean-Grecian term for the Great Beit Din). Interestingly, Rabbi Margolies [thought](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32665&st=&pgnum=4) that the three things that the Knesset taught over in [Avot 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pirkei_Avot.1.1?lang=bi) was a mirroring of the three tasks given to Ezra by King Artaxerxes ([Ezra 7:25](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezra.7.25?lang=bi)).

These three views more or less agree that the Knesset Hagedolah was the Sanhedrin of its time, the difference being what was the meaning of 120 elders as opposed to 71. However, there's another view:

The fourth view is by [Rabbi Yitzchak Halevi Hertzog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzhak_HaLevi_Herzog), who wrote in his essay "Historical Notes On The Halachot of the Sanhedrin", pt. 2, pg. 393-394, Sinai 3:5 that the Knesset Hagedolah was higher in rank than the Sanhedrin, and had different duties. Its duties comprised less of judicial decisions and more of spiritual ones, such as making sure Torah was being taught among Yisrael, creating fences around the Torah (סייג, see [Avot 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pirkei_Avot.1.1?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi)), organizing the structure of prayer, and so forth. According to Rabbi Hertzog, the reason they were comprised of 120 elders was because 120 equals 12 times 10, and 10 is an edah (עדה, see [Brachot 21b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Berakhot.21b.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). Each unit of ten men, each edah, symbolized one of the twelve tribes. He notes that though tribal mentality and awareness was considerably less significant during the Second Temple period, it still existed to a certain extent. For example, [Arachin 32b-33a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Arakhin.32b.15-33a.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [Tosfot in Gittin 36a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Gittin.36a.14?lang=bi&with=Tosafot&lang2=en), and [Ezra 6:17](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezra.6.17?lang=bi).<sup>4</sup>

Seemingly in agreement with Rabbi Hertzog's view (though not stated explicitly), [Rabbi Yehudah Leib Maimon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yehuda_Leib_Maimon) wrote in the book "Mazkeret - In memory of Rabbi Yitzchak Halevi Hertzog", pg. 566, that the Knesset was a council created to oversee the aliyah during Shivat Tzion. It was first headed by Zerubavel and Yehoshua ben Yehotzadak. The council's duties included maintaining contact with the communities that remained in the diaspora, supplying those that made aliyah with "silver, gold, goods, and livestock" ([Ezra 1:4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezra.1.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) and were in charge of all spiritual and physical matters pertaining to the olim. Rabbi Maimon, however, disagrees on the reasoning for there being 120 men. In his view, the council started out with the first 9-12 leaders of the aliyah, then expanded to include all of the heads of the families, which is why it is stated in some sources that they amounted to 85 men ([Yerushalmi Megillah 6b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jerusalem_Talmud_Megillah.6b.3?vhe=Mechon_Mamre_Talmud_Yerushalmi&lang=bi), [Ruth Rabbah 4:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ruth_Rabbah.4.5?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=bi)) (in Nechemiah 10, 83 are listed, to which Chaggai and Zechariah are probable additions and Malachi was probably Ezra). Finally, the number expanded to 120 to reflect the ties of the council with the Jews in all 120 states in the Medo-Persian empire ([Daniel 6:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Daniel.6.2?lang=bi)).

Side-note: [Eliezer Finkelstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Finkelstein), who mentioned Rabbi Hertzog's view in his book "The Pharisees and the Men of the Great Synagogue", points out that the word "edah" during the Second Temple period and afterwards, was synonymous with "knesset", "beit din" (court) and "sanhedri", comparing sources such as [Mishna Sotah 7:8](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Sotah.7.8?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi) with [Tosefta Makot 4:6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tosefta_Makkot.4.6?vhe=Tosefta_Makkot_-_Machon_Mamre&lang=bi) (the chazan of the knesset is the chazan of the court), and [Yalkut Shimoni 469:15](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Torah.469.15?vhe=Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Torah&lang=bi) and [Bamidbar Rabbah 16:21](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bamidbar_Rabbah.16.21?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=bi) (edah equals beit din and sanhedri), so this strengthens Rabbi Hertzog's view that there's a connection between the edah, the Sanhedrin, the court and the Knesset Hagedolah.

Finkelstein himself believed that the Knesset Hagedolah was some sort of central court, higher than the other courts/sanhedrins of the time, but still very much in charge of judicial rulings (unlike Rabbi Hertzog's position).

[Rabbi Prof. Ezra Tzion Melamed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ezra_Zion_Melamed) in his book "An Introduction to Talmudic Literature", pg. 44-45 and footnote 43, opined that the Knesset was the Sanhedrin of its time. One piece of evidence he brings is that in [Bamidbar 27:19](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.27.19?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) it says:

> "...and before the whole community..."

"Community", from Hebrew "עדה" is translated by the Targum as "כנישתא", which in Hebrew is "כנסת", and on this verse it says in [Yoma 73b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yoma.73b.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> "“Even all the congregation”; this is a reference to the Sanhedrin".

However, he doesn't appear to offer an explanation on why the Knesset had 120 members.

---

<sup>1</sup> One possible explanation can be found in [Eliyahu Bickerman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elias_Joseph_Bickerman)'s short essay on the Sanhedrin, [here](https://www-jstor-org.nli.idm.oclc.org/stable/pdf/23544026.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A8e2394b149ec3bec784906bd70a74d0e).

<sup>2</sup> For more on the contradicting sources, see Eliezer Finkelstein's "The Pharisees and the Men of the Great Synagogue" and [Avraham Büchler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_B%C3%BCchler)'s "Ha'Sanhedrin".

<sup>3</sup> Which is neither of the [two](https://hebrewbooks.org/20976) [editions](https://hebrewbooks.org/32665) available on Hebrewbooks.

<sup>4</sup> And I think we can also add the 72 elders who wrote the Septuagint, who, [according to the Letter of Aristeas](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Letter_of_Aristeas?lang=bi), were made up of six men from each tribe, and also [Pesachim 4a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pesachim.4a.3-4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

Comment: Interesting. Interesting, too, that all the views you cite are from very recent sources. There's nothing new about the question that implies no one older should have written on it. Did no one else, that you know of?

Comment: @msh210 perhaps there are. I haven't gotten that far back in my research. I offered up what I know.

Comment: Given that the last member of the Great Assembly lived about 200 years after Ezra, I see no reason to assume that the members of this body all co-existed. Does it not make more sense to say that the anshei knesses haggedolah are simply the different people who occupied the Sanhedrin during this period? There is obviously some crossover, but some died and were replaced. I don’t recall ever seeing a single source that suggests otherwise.

Comment: @ShimonbM I hope you're aware that most traditional sources (including commentators of the last 1500 years or so) hold that Shimon Hatzaddik knew Ezra. What's known as the "Jewish chronology". But say we go per your view. If they were different members of the Sanhedrin, why make mention of the number 120? Or 85? Neither are numbers commonly associated with the Sanhedrin...

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “Jewish chronology”… But notwithstanding, I don’t know of any classical source that uses the word Sanhedrin in reference to these people. They comprised a few generations of individuals, who are classed (for homiletic reasons) as the anshei knesses haggedolah. Why is it necessary to view them all as contemporaries? Are there rabbinic sources that explicitly attest that they were?

Comment: @ShimonbM if it was not one unified contemporaneous body, why were they referred to as such? I.e., why give them a special title and not simply call them "the beit din"? A number of sources about the Knesset seem to me to back the view that it was comprised of contemporaries. For example: [Avot D'Rabbi Natan 1:3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Avot_D'Rabbi_Natan.1.3?vhe=Talmud_Bavli,_Vilna_1883_ed.&lang=bi), [Beresheet Rabbah 35:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bereishit_Rabbah.35.2?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=bi),

Comment: [Megillah 2a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Megillah.2a.6?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=en), [Mishne Torah, order of transmission 7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Transmission_of_the_Oral_Law.7?vhe=Wikisource_Mishneh_Torah&lang=bi) and so forth. And what I meant by Jewish chronology is your view that Shimon Hatzaddik lived 200 years after Ezra, which is only correct per the secular dating of the Tanach and the life of Shimon, but not according to the traditional Jewish dating, which has Shimon very likely having known Ezra at least for a few years.